# TLS not working at all for Ubuntu in WSL

Tags: windows, ssl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tls

I recently reinstalled my computer and installed Linux Subsystem which I always do. So this is a complete new install. When I wanted to run *composer* I noticed something strange. It failed because it was unable to establish a TLS connection.

```
 [RuntimeException]  Failed to clone https://github.com/inquam/colors.php via https, ssh protocols, aborting.

 - https://github.com/inquam/colors.php    Cloning into bare repository '/home/danlil/.cache/composer/vcs/https---
github.com-inquam-colors.php'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/inquam/colors.php/': gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

 - git@github.com:inquam/colors.php
    Cloning into bare repository '/home/danlil/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-inquam-colors.php'...
    Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
    Permission denied (public key).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

After trying a bit more I noticed that this happens no matter which GitHub repository I try to clone via https and it also applies to any connection via *curl* or other commands that connect using TLS. I have tried several proposed solutions in other threads like updating *ca-certificates*, reinstalling *Ubuntu* on Windows 10, downloading *https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem* and pointing to that in *php.ini*, making sure *ipv6* is not the preferred method in *Ubuntu* etc.

Previously when I have used *Ubuntu* in *Windows 10* I have just installed and everything has worked without any issues like this at all.

Testing the Windows version of GIT and worked fine.

To demonstrate it seems to affect every Bash application I tested the following too

```
me@DATHREADRIPPER:/mnt/e/src$ **php -r 'echo 
file_get_contents("https://packagist.org/packages.json");'**

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in Command line 
code on line 1
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://packagist.org/packages.json): failed to open stream: operation failed in Command line code on line 1
```

and

```
me@DATHREADRIPPER:/mnt/e/src$ **wget https://www.youtube.com/**

--2018-04-22 19:51:13--  https://www.youtube.com/
Resolving www.youtube.com (www.youtube.com)... 172.217.21.174, 216.58.207.206, 216.58.211.142, ...
Connecting to www.youtube.com (www.youtube.com)|172.217.21.174|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

The version installed is

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```